# How to fill a new column based on data from other column during EF migration?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a database connected with my C# project using Entity Framework. I have a field "DealActive" of type `int`, which is filled with 1s and 0s. I want to change this field to the `bool` type. Is there a way in EF to only change the field type from `int` to `bool` and change each `1` to `true` and `0` to `false`? Or do I have to add a new field of type `bool` and fill it with `true` and `false` values? Is there any way to at least do this within the migration, or do I have to create it empty and fill the data by myself with another function?

Here is the migration code for adding a new `bool` column.

```
namespace MYPROJECT.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class MigrationName: DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            AddColumn("dbo.Deals", "Active", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false));
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropColumn("dbo.Deals", "Active");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Generated migrations are not off-limits. You can inject your custom SQL code in `Up()` and `Down()` methods. So, if EF will not give you what you want, you can always write your own SQL and make it part of the migration.

Comment: @TanveerBadar Which way can be done in SQL? changing the type of column, or only moving data from int column to a new bool column?

Comment: You'll need to lookup the exact syntax for the DB you are targeting, but IIRC there's a [`Sql()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/operations) method available in the base class `DbMigration` which lets you specify any custom SQL you want. P.S.: It appears EF core does things slightly differently than EF 6.x.